# How to map social credentials with custom ones

Tags: single-sign-on, federated-identity, ibm-api-management

My company has userbase of course, but I want to allow users to login and use my applications with their social accounts e.g. Outlook, Facebook, Gmail. Something that is usually not clear to me when I read resources on the Internet on the topic is how to map the social credentials with ones in our database? I know we should use an API platform or something like that, but the user identity part is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to, as you noted, tap into the provided response and transform or link or provision it to existing identities in your own userbase. A lot of this depends on your method of delegating authentication to external provides and things they expose back to you as part of the user profile. You basically need to grab the user profile, parse it and then determine which field can be used to link that profile to an existing account, and then establish the authentication session based on the final result.

Here is a link to a technical walkthrough that describes the same process with an SSO solution: https://apereo.github.io/2018/04/20/cas-delegated-authn-account-linking/